# How can I omitt certain lines from an Nmap output scan?

Tags: python, linux, bash, nmap

I am running the command `nmap -v --script ssl-cert paypal.com -T4`

I get a huge output which has a lot of info that I don't need.

Here is the full output (I've clipped the part where the actual certificate key is generated):

```
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-10-26 10:50 EDT
NSE: Loaded 1 scripts for scanning.
NSE: Script Pre-scanning.
Initiating NSE at 10:50
Completed NSE at 10:50, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating Ping Scan at 10:50
Scanning paypal.com (64.4.250.37) [4 ports]
Completed Ping Scan at 10:50, 0.15s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 10:50
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 10:50, 0.05s elapsed
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 10:50
Scanning paypal.com (64.4.250.37) [1000 ports]
Discovered open port 110/tcp on 64.4.250.37
Discovered open port 135/tcp on 64.4.250.37
Discovered open port 143/tcp on 64.4.250.37
Discovered open port 80/tcp on 64.4.250.37
Discovered open port 25/tcp on 64.4.250.37
Discovered open port 443/tcp on 64.4.250.37
Stats: 0:00:05 elapsed; 0 hosts completed (1 up), 1 undergoing SYN Stealth Scan
SYN Stealth Scan Timing: About 2.07% done; ETC: 10:55 (0:04:44 remaining)
Discovered open port 21/tcp on 64.4.250.37
Discovered open port 8008/tcp on 64.4.250.37
Discovered open port 8010/tcp on 64.4.250.37
Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 10:51, 19.20s elapsed (1000 total ports)
NSE: Script scanning 64.4.250.37.
Initiating NSE at 10:51
Completed NSE at 10:51, 29.66s elapsed
Nmap scan report for paypal.com (64.4.250.37)
Host is up (0.12s latency).
Other addresses for paypal.com (not scanned): 64.4.250.36
Not shown: 536 filtered ports, 455 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
110/tcp  open  pop3
135/tcp  open  msrpc
143/tcp  open  imap
443/tcp  open  https
| ssl-cert: Subject: commonName=paypal.com/organizationName=PayPal, Inc./stateOrProvinceName=California/countryName=US/localityName=San Jose/organizationalUnitName=PayPal Production
| Subject Alternative Name: DNS:paypal.com
| Issuer: commonName=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA/organizationName=DigiCert Inc/countryName=US/organizationalUnitName=www.digicert.com
| Public Key type: rsa
| Public Key bits: 2048
| Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
| Not valid before: 2018-10-22T00:00:00
| Not valid after:  2020-11-18T12:00:00
| MD5:   7705 9f8d cc8d d8a0 0835 e9ff cd9e 644f
| SHA-1: 595b 7897 7448 af87 cd2a 3bb9 5469 72e1 7e4e 7cec
| -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
 *clipped data*
|_-----END CERTIFICATE-----
8008/tcp open  http
8010/tcp open  xmpp

NSE: Script Post-scanning.
Initiating NSE at 10:51
Completed NSE at 10:51, 0.00s elapsed
Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 49.41 seconds
           Raw packets sent: 2621 (115.300KB) | Rcvd: 482 (19.420KB)
```

As you can see there is a bunch of stuff in here. I only need the lines that are between the `443` and `------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-------` fields.

Is there a way to omitt the rest of the retrieved data?

I've tried a way that isn't very efficient. We can see that there are a total of 10 lines that I only need in this scan: From `ssl-cert: Subject:` to `SHA-1`.

What I did so far is basically a python script that runs the nmap command from the beginning `nmap -v --script ssl-cert T4 | grep '*keyword from each line here*'`...

So my scan takes about 20 minutes because I'm running it like 10 times.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Pipe it through `grep '^[|] [^-]'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
... |  sed -n '/^443/,/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/p'
```

you may need to fine tune the matched patterns if there are false positives...

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
nmap -v --script ssl-cert paypal.com -T4 | sed -En '/(^\|\s[a-zA-Z]+)/p'
```

- `-E` Active the extended regexp, thus we can use `()`and `+`
- `-n` To suppress printing of pattern space
- `(^\|\s[a-zA-Z]+)` search a stream that start (`^`) with `|` character (need to scape "`\|`" it to correctly handle), followed by a space (`\s`) and followed by a letter bweteen a-z and A-Z (upper and lowercase) (`[a-zA-Z]`) 1 or more times (`+`)
- `\...\p` the `p` in the pattern parameters is for printing the match on the `stdout`